# Disable word breakings in SharePoint 2010 search

Tags: search, configuration, sharepoint-2010

Short question:
Is it possible in SharePoint 2010 to disable word breaking in the search engine?

Long question:
SharePoint search engine breaks up words in the index. For example: motorcycle will be indexed as motor and cycle. So a search for motor will result in a hit on motorcycle.

A customer would like to disable this functionality. Is that possible? So that a search for motor will result in only motor and not motorcycle?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but if you use Quotes around your key term i.e. "MotorCycle" , then you should get results with exact match and not for motor or for cycle.

Also most of search engine including bing, google and sp2010 search uses same behaviour

Sandeep

Comment: The problem is not to search for the hole word motorcycle. What we would like to achieve is that a search for "motor" would exlude hits on "motorcycle".

Comment: (if not the word "motor" also exists in the document off course)